# Watson Developer Cloud & Twisted Install With Error Code 1

Tags: python, twisted, ibm-watson, watson

I am trying to connect to the Watson Developer Cloud API, and am having issues installing Watson Developer Cloud. I am using

```
pip install --upgrade "watson-developer-cloud>=1.2.1
```

The install gets hung up on the install of Twisted. I have tried pip install twisted and installing using "Twisted-17.9.0.tar.bz2" from the Twisted site.

https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/python.html?python

I have exhausted all my resources. **Any ideas how to resolve the following error?**

Error Code 1

[image: Error]

Comment: Do you get this error when working with a new Python virtual environment?  If you have not already, please try that.

Comment: I received the same error message when using the virtual environment (it looked like (env) C:\>pip install twisted). I was actually able to install Twisted when I used the Anaconda Prompt "conda install twisted". I can see the twisted files in my Anaconda directory, but have not been able to install Watson Developer Cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you by chance running in a VM?  If you are, try installing it on a stand alone (not VM) machine.

I had a similar issue trying to get Watson Developer going on a VM and it also stuck on the Twisted component - but i was able to take the (almost) same environment on a stand alone basis (not VM) and it installed.

I assumed that I had somehow not configured the interface correctly (which is probably true) - but it installed on the stand alone without issue.

Comment: I actually was using a VM! I tried on my personal computer and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to install it as Administrator
- Update your pip
- Before installing Watson, run this:

  ```
  xcode-select --install
  ```